# Android same method called twice

Tags: java, android

I have a method that runs when the app is opened. It is called from onCreate. But I also call it from onResume. The problem I have is that at the moment it is running twice when the app opens. Is there a way to stop this or a better way to implement what I am trying to achieve?

Thanks

Comment: What's with the downvotes without comment?  It should be illegal to "downvote and run".  How else can a noob learn?  Anyway, this was causing me trouble by double launching a thread.  As obvious as the answer is, I'm glad this was the first google result.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

When an activity starts, `onCreate()` is called first and then `onResume()` is called,if you want it to be called only once, remove the call in `onCreate()`.

calling the method in onResume() will ensure that the method is called when the activity regains focus, like after back press etc..

Answer (score 0):

Why not to use it only in onResume()? It IS called after onCreate anyway.

viz. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#ActivityLifecycle

Answer (score 0):

Activity lifecycle needed steps:

Want to Start the Activity?

> Activity Starts => onCreate() => onStart() => onResume() => Activity
>   is running

Want to shut it down?

> Running => onPause() => onStop() =>onDestroy() => Activity is finally
>   shut down.

I recomend you to read this article of the official documentation:
[Activity](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html)